# Find out if there is nesting of comments in C file using python script

Tags: c, python-3.x, automation

This is a code to find out if there is nesting of comment in a sample.c file but I am getting this **error:nothing to repeat**. Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

```
import re

with open('sample.c',mode='r') as myfile:
    flist = myfile.readlines()

flag1 = False

for j in range(len(flist)):
    if re.search('/*',flist[j]):
        if flag1:
            print(f'Warning: Nested comment at line number {j+1}')
        else:
            flag1 = True
    if flag1:
        if re.search('*/',flist[j]):
            flag1 = False
```

Comment: * is a regex repeat specifier. There is nothing repeatable before it. So there is nothing to repeat. Try escaping the *: re.search('\\*/',flist[j]):

Comment: @hellork Please turn that into an answer. Ideally by testing it and showing the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Python regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) (RE) syntax, `*` is a *special character* indicating a match of 0 or more repeats of the previous RE. The pattern, `'*/'` is saying "repeat nothing" because there is "nothing to repeat." If not using the repeat specifier, the thing to do is to escape it with a `\` character, like so: `\*`. The modified lines make the program work as intended:

```
        if re.search('/\*',flist[j]):
...
        if re.search('\*/',flist[j]):
```

This still doesn't handle the case where comment nesting occurs on the same line.

```
/* this is a /* nested comment */ */
```

For that, we need to match multiple instances of `/*`. The following modification does this.

```
        if flag1 or re.search('/\*.*/\*',flist[j]):
            print(f'Warning: Nested comment at line number {j+1}')
```

Comment: hi @hellork, can u please explain why did you use this '/\*.*/\*'  expression? I mean what is its importance?

Comment: It matches the line /* this is a /* nested comment */ */. You can look at the match object to see.